# Is every uniformity for a metrizable topology metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, uniform-spaces

Let $X$ be a metrizable topological space, and let $U$ be a uniformity which induces the topology on $X$.  My question is, is $U$ necessarily metrizable?  That is, is $U$ induced by some metric on $X$?

If not, is there an example of a uniformity for a metrizable topology which isn’t induced by any metric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No ,this is not the case. I had an answer to a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2545169/4280). The example mentioned there: take the reals in the standard topology and let $\mathcal{U}_f$ be the so-called *fine uniformity* on the reals (the finest uniformity on the set that induces the same topology). Then this uniformity is not metrisable by standard results quoted in [this survey paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.3249.pdf). Beware, there is a lot of theory behind this (the paper also quotes bornological conditions, which will please the OP).

Comment: Haha yeah, it does please me.